# Adding the column value to the array in another column when the value is missing

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe with a column that contains an arraylist containing structs of form (key, score), i.e. the value column below.
In addition, I have another column called item that contains a string.

```
root
 |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- score: double (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- item: string (nullable = true)
```

When the item is not null, I want to search the arraylist to see if the item is present in value.key(s). If it is not present, append (item, min) to the arraylist in value column. Here, min is the minimum value for the scores in the arraylist. 
I need to preserve the order of elements in arraylist and append the new struct to the end of the list.

Sample input:

```
+-----------------------------------+------+------+
| value                             |  id  | item |
+-----------------------------------+------+------+
|[[e1, 0.4] , [e2, 0.3]]            | 1    | e3   |
|[[e1, 0.4] , [e2, 0.3], [e3, 0.2]] | 2    | e4   |
|[[e1, 0.4] , [e2, 0.3]]            | 3    | e1   |
|[[e1, 0.4] , [e2, 0.3]]            | 4    | null |
+-----------------------------------+------+------+
```

Sample output:

```
+------------------------------------------------+------+------+
| value                                          |  id  | item |
+------------------------------------------------+------+------+
|[[e1, 0.4] , [e2, 0.3], [e3, 0.3]]              | 1    | e3   |
|[[e1, 0.4] , [e2, 0.3], [e3, 0.2], [e4, 0.2]]   | 2    | e4   |
|[[e1, 0.4] , [e2, 0.3]]                         | 3    | e1   |
|[[e1, 0.4] , [e2, 0.3]]                         | 4    | null |
+------------------------------------------------+------+------+
```

How would the solution would be different, if I want to add the new (key, score) to the a specific position in the list? (e.g. start or middle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `udf` function to achieve it.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,ArrayType,StringType,DoubleType

def contains(values,item):
    if not item:
        return values
    keys = [pair['key'] for pair in values]
    if item not in keys:
        scores = [pair['score'] for pair in values]
        values.append({'key':item,'score':min(scores)})
    return values

contains_udf = F.udf(contains,ArrayType(StructType([StructField('key', StringType()),
                                                    StructField('score', DoubleType())])))
df = df.withColumn("value", contains_udf('value','item'))
df.show(truncate = False)

+--------------------------------------------+---+----+
|value                                       |id |item|
+--------------------------------------------+---+----+
|[[e1, 0.4], [e2, 0.3], [e3, 0.3]]           |1  |e3  |
|[[e1, 0.4], [e2, 0.3], [e3, 0.2], [e4, 0.2]]|2  |e4  |
|[[e1, 0.4], [e2, 0.3]]                      |3  |e1  |
|[[e1, 0.4], [e2, 0.3]]                      |4  |null|
+--------------------------------------------+---+----+
```